# jQuery Click Working Once, not Twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scope

In the scope of a function, I am loading HTML to display in a Bootstrap modal via AJAX. The AJAX load is expensive, and I want to cache the content that it loads. However, the rows of a table in the HTML can change dynamically, and need click listeners bound to them.

I don't know how best to explain the situation other than posting some code.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vvc1j1eh/1/

So the big question would be, why does the first load click work the first time, but not after I try to re-use the cached content? Also why does the second load in scope click work every time?

**Edit: Better Explanation of the Problem**

Load the page, and click "Load" to show the dialog. If you click on a row, an alert will pop up with the row you clicked on. Click anywhere outside of the dialog to hide it, and click "Load" again. This time, when you click rows the alert message won't pop up.

If you do the exact same process for the Load With Right Scope button, you will still get alerts when clicking on rows the second time the dialog is displayed.

**Delegation:**

It's hard to explain in an example, but the content "document" page is also loaded dynamically by AJAX along with multiple pages. These multiple pages are shown and hidden as the user navigates the webapp, so I can't just bind a global listener to the document.

This would be the closest equivalent of what I was doing when trying delegation:

```
var $data = expensiveAjaxLoad();
$data.on('click', 'tbody td', function() {
    alert($(this).html());
});
$('#load').click(function() {
    addRowsAndListeners($data);

    $('#content').html($data);
    $('#modal').modal('show');
});
```

It still doesn't answer the **big question**, which is why do the events not bind the second time? They bind the first time, and as I'm debugging, there doesn't seem to be any change to the scope variable `$data`.

**StackSnippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Scope of the function

  //$data works the first time, but additional row
  //clicks don't register events
  var $data = expensiveAjaxLoad();
  $('#load').click(function() {
    addRowsAndListeners($data);

    $('#content').html($data);
    $('#modal').modal('show');
  });

  //Why does this work?
  $('#load-scope').click(function() {
    var $better = expensiveAjaxLoad();
    addRowsAndListeners($better);

    $('#content').html($better);
    $('#modal').modal('show');
  });
});

function expensiveAjaxLoad() {    
  var html = [];
  html.push('<table><tbody>');
  html.push('</tbody></table>');
  return $(html.join(''));
}

function addRowsAndListeners($data) {
  var html = [];
  //Rows can vary, don't need to recreate the entire table
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    html.push('<tr><td>Row ');
    html.push((i + 1));
    html.push('</td></tr>');
  }
  $('tbody', $data).html(html.join(''));

  //Something here is not binding correctly
  $('tbody td', $data).click(function() {
    alert($(this).html());
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>Hello Alice</h1>
            <button id="load">Load</button>
            <button id="load-scope">Load With Right Scope</button>
        </div>
        <div id="modal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Title</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="content" class="modal-body">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Update:**

Here is a new Fiddle with the minimum amount of my current production code.

http://jsfiddle.net/0vb2psv4/1/

Comment: Instead of using JSFiddle, try the new [StackSnippets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?cb=1)

Comment: both are working fine for me, so what does your console output?

Comment: @JayBlanchard No, check the fiddle for the HTML

Comment: @Igoel There is no output, the content loads correctly, but if you click "Load" a second time and try clicking on the rows, the alert message does not show anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use event delegation on document, as there are dynamicaly created elements. Also move the click event binding in document ready instead of function addRowsAndListeners()

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/vvc1j1eh/3/)

```
 $(document).on('click','tbody td',function() {
        alert($(this).html());
    });
```

UPDATE: With your original code, delegate it on content (container of table or model body) as your table is also dynamic

```
$("#content").on('click', 'tbody tr', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.hasClass('selectable')) {
                $this.toggleClass('success');
            }
        });
```

[updated fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/0vb2psv4/3/)

Comment: While this works in the example, the `document` is also loaded dynamically as a page, and multiple pages are added and removed from the display. I've tried delegation, but it doesn't work in my code. I'll see if I can get a better example

Comment: I updated your code( fiddle example ). may be your provide actual problem code. Solution here is, if you create dynamic elements and need to have event handler working on them, delegate them.

Comment: I updated my question with a section on the delegation that I've tried. Why wouldn't delegation work like what I posted? `$data` doesn't change, just its `innerHTML`, so I would think that the event would stay working

Comment: I added a new fiddle with the production code I've got running

Comment: I think that's as close as I'll get to it. Do you know why jQuery handles the event the first time but not the second?

Comment: Second time you replace the tr with new one and event is gone too, that's why delegate on upper existing parent and not on dynamic.

Comment: I understand that, but why doesn't the new event creation work? I'm not trying to re-use the old event, I'm trying to unbind it and bind a new event to the new tr rows

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0vb2psv4/13/ This one unbind old and bind them again but after table is appended to content.

Comment: That's the solution =) I was trying to set up the listeners before appending it to the dialog instead of after

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve your desired functionality by altering your `$('#load').click()`: [**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/b7pxhfj0/)

```
$('#load').on("click", function() { //changed to on("click")
    addRowsAndListeners($data);

    $('#content').html($data);
    $('#modal').modal('show');

    //remove the on("click") and set up a new on("click") to just show the modal     
    $('#load').off("click").on("click", function() { 
        $('#modal').modal('show');
        //you could add additional logic in here if you need to conditionally redo the ajax call
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're adding rows jQuery is not aware of them. You need to delegate the click event -

```
$(document).on('click', 'tbody td', function() {
    alert($(this).html());
});
```