# jQuery click on leaflet map is working the first time, but not the second

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, leaflet

EDIT : I have recreated the issue on this website, if you want to check : http://leafletdev1.id-interactive.info/

I am truely sorry, i saw a lot of posts that looks like my problem, but none of them are working as I think it is not exactly related on the same subject. I am pretty sure my issue is somehow linked to this : [jQuery Click Working Once, not Twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25892990/jquery-click-working-once-not-twic), but... I am a real newbie in ajax, and I can't really understand everything of what is going on here...

I have a wordpress website that is using the **freemium version** of the plugin **Leaflet Maps Marker v3.12.4**. Here, I am displaying a map, with **popups** that open when I **click the marker linked to them** :

[image]

What I am trying to achieve, is that **when I click on a "Bouton d'action" button**, it click the marker in order to **open the popup**. And it is actually working, except that when I move on the map, zoom, dezoom, or do any actual action, **the clicks won't work anymore**, and no more popups will open.

[image]

Here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.marker1').click(function () {
        let d = 250;
        setTimeout(function () {
            let markersDOM = $('.leaflet-marker-pane img');
            let marker = null;
            let markerTitle = null;

            for (var i = 0; i < markersDOM.length; i++) {
                markerTitle = markersDOM[i];
                marker = markersDOM[i].getAttribute("title");
                if (marker === "marker1") {
                    $(markerTitle).click();
                }
            }
        }, d);
    });
});
```

Do you know what is happening here ? I am a little lost...

Thanks a lot for reading this.

Comment: I dont know leaflet specifically but do you really have to set the content for the popups all over? Isnt there an easy show or hide method? Thats at least how google maps work

Comment: I... Don't know... There may be a better way of doing this, I am kind of trying to find my way throught this... I think I saw a way to "toggle" them

Comment: Always read the manual first. That is usually your best bet!

Comment: Have you tried replacing `$('.marker1').click(function () {` with `$("body").on('click', '.marker1', function(e) {` ?

Comment: I just tried, and no... it is not working... Thanks a lot for your answer anyway !
I think the problem come from how I handle the click on the markers...

Comment: Should be `marker = markersDOM[i].getAttribute("title");` not `markerTile`? Can you share your website to see / debug it live?

Comment: I recreated the issue on another website, here it is : you can test everything here : http://leafletdev1.id-interactive.info/